# Why does my render function render an empty <body> when I add a <Router> to my test in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the below scenario with React Router V3. Based on the step prop, I set some state variables and then render the  component. The correct screen is then displayed based on the props passed to

```
const TestComponent = ({
  languageData,
  locale,
  route: { step },
}) => {
  const [showTiles, setShowTiles] = useState(true);
  const [showAdsSearch, setShowAdsSearch] = useState(false);
  const [showBasicSearch, setShowBasicSearch] = useState(false);
  const [showSubmitterFields, setShowSubmitterFields] = useState(false);

  const viewHome = () => {
    setShowBasicSearch(false);
    setShowSubmitterFields(false);
    setShowAdsSearch(false);
    setShowTiles(true);
  };

  const viewBasicSearch = () => {
    setShowBasicSearch(true);
    setShowSubmitterFields(false);
    setShowAdsSearch(false);
    setShowTiles(false);
  };

  const viewAdSearch = () => {
    setShowBasicSearch(false);
    setShowSubmitterFields(false);
    setShowAdsSearch(true);
    setShowTiles(false);
  };

  const viewCreateSubmitterProfileFields = () => {
    setShowBasicSearch(false);
    setShowSubmitterFields(true);
    setShowAdsSearch(false);
    setShowTiles(false);
  };

  const stepMap = new Map([
    [1, viewHome],
    [2, viewCreateSubmitterProfileFields],
    [3, viewBasicSearch],
    [4, viewAdSearch],
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentState = stepMap.get(step) || viewHome;
    currentState();
  }, [step]);

  if (Object.entries(languageData).length === 0) {
    return <ProgressCircle />;
  }

  return (
    <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={languageData}>
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        {(user) => (Object.keys(user).length > 0 ? (
          <HomeView
            className={styles.grayBg}
            showAdsSearch={showAdsSearch}
            setShowAdsSearch={setShowAdsSearch}
            showSubmitterFields={showSubmitterFields}
            setShowSubmitterFields={setShowSubmitterFields}
            showBasicSearch={showBasicSearch}
            setShowBasicSearch={setShowBasicSearch}
            showTiles={showTiles}
            setShowTiles={setShowTiles}
          />
        ) : <div>NO USER CONTEXT SET IN ROOT MODULE</div>)}
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
};
```

The home component:

```
export function Home({
  showTiles,
  setShowTiles,
  showBasicSearch,
  setShowBasicSearch,
  showAdsSearch,
  setShowAdsSearch,
  showSubmitterFields,
  setShowSubmitterFields,
}) {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <HeaderSection
        setShowBasicSearch={setShowBasicSearch}
        showBasicSearch={showBasicSearch}
        setShowTiles={setShowTiles}
        setShowAdsSearch={setShowAdsSearch}
        setSubmitterIdToView={setSubmitterIdToView}
        setSubmitterName={setSubmitterName}
        setShowSubmitterFields={setShowSubmitterFields}
      />
      <div id="home" className={styles.grayBgForHome}>
        {showTiles && (
          <TilesView
            setShowBasicSearch={setShowBasicSearch}
            setShowTiles={setShowTiles}
            setShowAdsSearch={setShowAdsSearch}
            showAdsSearch={showAdsSearch}
            showSubmitterFields={showSubmitterFields}
            setShowSubmitterFields={setShowSubmitterFields}
          />
        )}
        {showBasicSearch && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1 className={styles.headingText}>
              Search Submitter Profile
            </h1>
            <ConnectedBasicSearch/>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {showAdsSearch && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1 className={styles.headingText}>
              Advanced Search Submitter Profile
            </h1>
            <ConnectedAdvancedSearch/>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {showSubmitterFields && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1 className={styles.headingText}>Create Submitter Profile</h1>
            <ConnectedSubmitterProfile/>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
      <FooterSection />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

In my test, I have the below. What I am trying to do is render Home with step = 1 which should display the Tiles component. Then I click on the #basicSearchTile which is a
Link to /submitter-profile/basic-search and want to check for certain elements being displayed:

```
async function clickElement(container, selector) {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const element = container.querySelector(selector);
  await user.click(element);
}

async function checkDisplayed(container, selector, shouldBeDisplayed) {
  const element = container.querySelector(selector);
  if (shouldBeDisplayed) {
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  } else {
    expect(element).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  }
}

const props1 = {
  languageData: { intlKeyMock: 'intlValueMock' },
  locale: 'localeMock',
  route: { step: 1 },
};
const props2 = {
  languageData: { intlKeyMock: 'intlValueMock' },
  locale: 'localeMock',
  route: { step: 2 },
};
const props3 = {
  languageData: { intlKeyMock: 'intlValueMock' },
  locale: 'localeMock',
  route: { step: 3 },
};
const props4 = {
  languageData: { intlKeyMock: 'intlValueMock' },
  locale: 'localeMock',
  route: { step: 4 },
};

  describe('Navigation tests', () => {
    it('invalid submitterId on save for edit profile', async () => {
      const { container } = render(
        <Router initialEntries={['/submitter-profile']} history={createMemoryHistory()}>
          <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}>
            <Route path="/" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props1} />} />
            <Route path="/submitter-profile" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props1} />} />
            <Route path="/submitter-profile/basic-search" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props3} />} />
            <Route path="/submitter-profile/create" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props2} />} />
            <Route path="/submitter-profile/advanced-search" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props4} />} />
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </Router>
      );
      screen.debug();
      await clickElement(container, '#basicSearchTile');
      await clickElement(container, '#search-button');
      await clickElement(container, '#resultTableRowsubmitterId123');
      await clickElement(container, '#editToggle');
      await clickElement(container, '#saveButton');
      screen.debug();
      await checkDisplayed(container, '#responseModalMsg', true);
      await checkTextValue(container, '#responseModal', 'Must enter a valid value for Submitter ID.');
      await clickElement(container, '#responseModal');
      await checkDisplayed(container, '#responseModalMsg', false);
    });
});
```

However, whenever i use render, the screen.debug() calls are returning an empty body .

```
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

Also I have added the route definitions in case they are helpful.
**Routing in the app is working great. it is just the tests that I cannot get to work**

```
const Routes = [
  <Route
    key="submitter-profile-route"
    path="/submitter-profile"
    moduleName="axp-submissions-web-search-submitter-profile"
    step={1}
  />,
  <Route
    key="create-submitter-profile-route"
    path="/submitter-profile/create"
    moduleName="axp-submissions-web-search-submitter-profile"
    step={2}
  />,
  <Route
    key="basic-search-submitter-profile-route"
    path="/submitter-profile/basic-search"
    moduleName="axp-submissions-web-search-submitter-profile"
    step={3}
  />,
  <Route
    key="advanced-search-submitter-profile-route"
    path="/submitter-profile/advanced-search"
    moduleName="axp-submissions-web-search-submitter-profile"
    step={4}
  />];
```

Solution:  I was able to us Drews answer to mock my router like this

```
const TestHomeComponent = () => <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}><TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props1} /></UserContext.Provider>;
const TestBasicSearchComponent = () => <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}><TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props3} /></UserContext.Provider>;
const TestCreateComponent = () => <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}><TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props2} /></UserContext.Provider>;
const TestAdvSearchComponent = () => <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}><TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props4} /></UserContext.Provider>;

const { container, debug } = render(
  <Router initialEntries={['/submitter-profile']} history={createMemoryHistory()}>
    <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}>
      <Route path="/submitter-profile" component={TestHomeComponent} />
      <Route path="/submitter-profile/basic-search" component={TestBasicSearchComponent} />
      <Route path="/submitter-profile/create" component={TestCreateComponent} />
      <Route path="/submitter-profile/advanced-search" component={TestAdvSearchComponent} />
      <Route path="/" component={TestHomeComponent} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: I am not certain it's the exact cause of your testing issue, but you are missing rendering the routes into a `Routes` component. Nothing can be matched & rendered. There should be an invariant error outputted somewhere since the APIs are used incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for looking! Unfortunately I am using a fork of react-router V3 which it looks like doesn't include <Routes> as a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React-Router v3 [Route](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#route) component doesn't have an `element` prop, it has a [`component`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#component) prop. Update the test code to use the `component` prop and pass a reference to the component instead of JSX.

Be sure to also specify the routes in the inverse order of path specificity, e.g. render *more* specific paths before *less* specific paths.

Example:

```
describe('Navigation tests', () => {
  it('invalid submitterId on save for edit profile', async () => {
    const memoryHistory = createMemoryHistory();

    const { container } = render(
      <Router
        initialEntries={['/submitter-profile']}
        history={memoryHistory}
      >
        <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}>
          <Route
            path="/submitter-profile/basic-search"
            component={TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile}
          />
          <Route
            path="/submitter-profile/create"
            component={TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile}
          />
          <Route
            path="/submitter-profile/advanced-search"
            component={TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile}
          />
          <Route
            path="/submitter-profile"
            component={TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile}
          />
          <Route
            path="/"
            component={TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile}
          />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    );

    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer lead me to being able to fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

> I have added the route definitions in case they are helpful. Routing in the app is working great. it is just the tests that I cannot get to work.

In first, it seems correctly set up. But in your test, you use `render` from `@testing-library/react` to render component but this doesn't support **react-router v3**.

I'm just thinking here that you need a **Router** component to navigate in your tests.

I use `createMemoryHistory` from `history` here, because we need to create a history object first then pass it to the `Router`.

If can't find `createMemoryHistory` or no `history` yet, install it by doing `npm install --save history`.
Then, create a router like the below sample to allow you simulate navigation in your tests.

```
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

// ...

it('invalid submitterId on save for edit profile', async () => {
 const history = createMemoryHistory();
 history.push('/');

 const { container } = render(
 <Router history={history}>
   <UserContext.Provider value={loggedInUser}>
     <Route path="/" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props1} />} />
     <Route path="/submitter-profile" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props1} />} />
     <Route path="/submitter-profile/basic-search" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props3} />} />
     <Route path="/submitter-profile/create" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props2} />} />
     <Route path="/submitter-profile/advanced-search" element={<TestableAxpSubmissionsWebSearchSubmitterProfile {...props4} />} />
   </UserContext.Provider>
 </Router>
 );

 // ...
});
```